# Is this true for finite abelian groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

I'm trying to decompose abelian groups using the structure theorem for modules over PIDs.

Here is one I have proved:

> Let $G$ be a non-trivial abelian group whose prime decomposition of the order is $p_1^{\alpha_1}...p_k^{\alpha_k}$.
>
> Let $H_i$ be the Sylow $p_i$-subgroups of $G$ for each $1\leq i \leq k$.
>
> Then, $G\cong \prod_{i=1}^k H_i$.

Is this true?

Comment: It's true.  But you say you proved it?

Comment: In fact, it's true for all nilpotent groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $G$ is abelian, the map $\prod H_i \to G$ defined by $(h_1, \dots, h_k) \to h_1 \cdots h_k$ is a homomorphism. It's not hard to prove by induction on $k$ that this map is injective. (In brief: If $h_1 \cdots h_k = 1$, then $h_1^{\alpha_k} \cdots h_{k-1}^{\alpha_k} = 1$, and the order of each $h_i$ in the product is prime to $\alpha_k$.) Since $\# \prod H_i = \#G$, the map is therefore an isomorphism.